# Are .Net POCO's Threadsafe?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, thread-safety, visibility

This question might seem a bit odd but has to do with possible visibility issues. The question is inspired by a case in the Java programming language (>jdk5), consider:

```
public class InmutableValue {
  private int value;
  public InmutableValue(int value) {this.value = value;}
  public int getValue() {return value;}
}
```

Despite contrary belief, the class above is not threadsafe. In a multithreaded environment 'value' is not guaranteed to be visible to other threads. In order to make it threadsafe we need to enforce a 'happens-before' rule. This can be accomplished by marking the field 'final'.

This case made me wonder if the same is true for the .Net runtime. So take for example:

```
public class InmutableValue {
  private int value;
  public InmutableValue(int value) {this.value = value;}
  public int Value { get{return value;}}
}
```

As far as I know marking the value field as 'readonly' does not give the same guarantees as 'final' does for java (but I could be terribly wrong, hopefully). So do we need to mark fields as 'volatile' (or use memory barriers, etc.) to ensure visibility to other threads? Or are there other rules applied that ensure visibility?

Comment: `value` isn't visible to code outside of the `InmutableValue` class because it's `private`. That doesn't seem to be the definition of `visible` that you're using, though.

Comment: No indeed, I mean: will the value be visible to other threads without resorting to memory barriers or other means of synchronization? One difference with java is that in the CLR constructors only return their pointer after the fields have been assigned. So no partially initialized object in .Net, unlike Java.

Comment: I'm going to display my ignorance here, but doesn't "POCO" i.e. "Plain Old CLR Objects" imply that the thread-safety of any given object is exactly as it would be if EF ewas not involved? The definition of them is that there is no special EF logic in the classes themselves, so all the same thread-safety concerns of programming in CLR apply as usual.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what is really being asked here.

Comment: Do you mean Entity Framework by EF? That is not involved. It seems that immutable objects can only be safely shared over multiple threads when its inner fields are volatile or memory barriers are applied on access. But I can not confirm that and hoping someone else can.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure why I invoked Entity Framework, I was sure when I answered that somebody had mentioned it. I know the term 'POCO' from Entity Framework in any case, and had presumed that was the context of the question.

Comment: Could you maybe post some code that uses your ImmutableValue class from multiple threads and demonstrates a potential thread-safety issue such as a race condition or deadlock?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably fretting about cpu cores with a weak memory model, like the Alpha and Titanium.  That have a memory write buffer that can reorder memory writes, making it possible that the object reference is written before the *value* field value.  Perhaps inspired by Raymond Chen's blog?

You are missing an important detail though.  To create a threading race, there have to be two threads that *both* use the object reference.  One that creates the object and stores the reference, another that uses that reference.  *That* is fundamentally thread-unsafe, access to the shared object reference needs to be synchronized.  The synchronization code (like the *lock* statement) also ensures that the write-back buffer is flushed.  Which prevents the thread that reads the property from ever seeing a stale value.

Comment: So basically, the POJO is not threadsafe even though it is immutable and can only be made threadsafe by either declaring the fields volatile or by other means of synchronization code. .Net does not provide the same level of synchronization with readonly as java does with final?

Comment: You missed what I tried to explain by a mile.  Sharing *object references* between threads isn't thread-safe.  In any language, no matter the acronym.

Comment: So sharing a static initialized object isn't safe for sharing between threads?

Comment: It makes no difference, *readonly* variables are initialized by the constructor, before the statements in the body execute.

Comment: Exactly. Thread-safety of object initialization is irrelevant since any _correct_ program will use some form of synchronization when sharing the reference to the object, thereby ensuring the uninitialized object is never seen by another thread.
Thread-safe initialization as with Java `final` is relevant only when you need to maintain some properties (think security sandbox) even when your object is used in _incorrect_ programs.

Comment: @Daniel: Sometimes it's legitimate for one thread to store a reference and the other thread to read it, without synchronization, if the reader will work correctly regardless of whether it sees the new value or the previous one.  The question is what memory barriers, if any, are needed to ensure correctness in certain common scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, `readonly` keyword only ensures that the field will be assigned in a constructor, not anywhere else (inside the class).

And as far as constructor is [thread-safe in general meaning](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/fee30577-ba7e-486b-81bc-bdf7855acf38), once created object will return the same value:

```
static ImmutableValue imv = new ImmutableValue(123);

// thread 1, object is not created
imv.Value; // NullReferenceException, as usually

// thread 2, object is created
imv.Value; //123

// thread 3, object is created
imv.Value; //123
```

To edit `private` field you need to use Reflection, and yes, you will need to lock the object during such code execution to guarantee to freeze all threads that tries to read the value in this moment.

Comment: Is this supposed to answer the question about the thread-safety of the provided source code?

Comment: @Darin: You saw just a part of my answer

Comment: I saw what you posted. Now that you have added the second part it's better :-) So your conclusion is that this code is 100% thread safe on .NET?

Comment: I know, same goes for java's final keyword, though java final can solve visibility problems. By the way, your statement on readonly is not not entirely correct. readonly fields can also be initialized by means of a special marker called 'beforefieldinit' which initializes the field without a ctor ;-)

Comment: "readonly keyword only ensures that the field will be assigned in a constructor, not anywhere else" -- that's only half the truth. The `readonly` keyword also protects the members of custom structs: Direct change by compiler warning and indirect change via member methods at runtime.